# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable for a small range problem I am trying to work on

Tags: python, data-science

I am learning how to code. Pretty new to all this stuff. But why is little bit of code giving me a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error. I am in Jupyter

```
ranges = []
for i in range(len(Y)):
     x = max(Y[i]) - min(Y[i])
     ranges.append(x)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is ```Y```? It has ```None``` Value

Comment: `Y[i]` is `None` for one of the values of `i`.  Find it and fix it.  You can add `if Y[i] is None: print(i)` to your loop to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

As @TomKarzes points out, `Y[i]` is `None` for at least one value of `i`. Also, note in this scenario you have no reason to index over `i`: just index over the elements of `Y` instead as this adds readability. Combining this with the check for `None`, we get:

```
ranges = []
for item in Y:
    if item is None:
        pass # this means do nothing. You could also append None
    else:
        x = max(item) - min(item)
        ranges.append(x)
```

Finally, I will point out that in Python you can do all of this in just one line using a list comprehension via

```
ranges = [max(item) - min(item) for item in Y if item is not None]
```